# Как в Android Studio подключить в один проект другой, независимый от текущего

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, библиотеки

В сети много информации об этом не хитром деле, но мне все же не понятен один момент.

Есть 2 android - приложения. Для этих двух приложений существует общая библиотека. Эта схема успешно работала в Eclipse.

Сейчас же, когда перешел на Android Studio, я пытаюсь повторить тот же фокус (разными способами), но у меня не получается.

Я хочу сделать ссылку на указанный библиотечный проект. Чтоб все изменения сразу отражались во всех приложениях, к которым эта библиотека подключена. А все что у меня получается это с сделать копию библиотечного проекта. В таком случае не о какой общности библиотеки речи не идет.

Как быть?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то [как то так](http://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2014/10/02/an-alternative-multiproject-setup-for-android-studio/)

Comment: ваша ссылка не рабочая, к сожалению.

Comment: У меня  рабочая .. ну вот, тогда, [офф.дока](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup), только она несколько замудреная. Вообще, гуглите в сторону multiproject android studio, время будет, напишу ответ, разберетесь, сами напишите :). Вот еще [на SOF гайд есть](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31366602)

Comment: Да, это то что надо! Действительно непонятно почему в Google решили сделать именно такую работу с библиотеками? Почему не реализовали беспроблемное подключение внешних проектов?

Comment: Google в данном случае ничего не решал. Android Studio - форк IntelliJ IDEA, продукт JetBrains, но даже это здесь не влияет особо, такова схема подключения зависимостей в сборщике Gradle, который AS использует в своих проектах. Gradle - независимый инструмент и создан не Google. Со своей стороны замечу, что если с ним разобраться, то вы будете думать о нем гораздо лучше, это очень мощный и удобный инструмент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Android Studio* для сборки проекта использует систему сборки *Gradle*, поэтому решается данный вопрос через возможности именно данной системы сборки, а не непосредственно *Android Studio*

Для того, чтобы подключить в свой проект другой, независимый от текущего, проект (например, разрабатываемую вами же библиотеку) в *Android Studio*, необходимо в файле `settings.gradle` текущего проекта добавить ссылку на другой проект:

```
include ':myLibrary'
project(':myLibrary').projectDir = new File('../MyProjects/myLibrary')
```

Здесь мы подключаем к текущему проекту проект *myLibrary*.

*../MyProjects/myLibrary* - путь до подключаемого проекта.

Ссылка на подключенный проект появится в дереве файлов *Android Studio*, при редактировании вы будете вносить изменения непосредственно в сам проект, а не его копию в текущем проекте.

Теперь при сборке вашего текущего проекта в него будет включен и подключенный проект, при этом данный проект не будет импортирован в текущий и вы можете вносить изменения в тот подключенный проект, тогда они будут учитываться при следующей сборке во всех проектах, в которых он подключен таким образом.

[Пост на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31366602) с картинками

Comment: Как я уже написал выше - получилось. Однако я столкнулся с тем же косяком, от которого, мне казалось, я убежал перейдя с Eclipse. Дизайнер студии не видит ресурсов, из библиотеки подключенной таким образом. Точнее если править XML, в всплывающей подсказке я найду этот ресурс(например цвет), а вот на превью он не отобразиться. Вместо цвета не будет ничего.

Comment: @ConstantinePl, у вас получилось подключить библиотеку так как написано выше? У меня не получается. Проект не видит классов этой библиотеки :(

Comment: в settings.gradle я сделал записи как показано выше. В проектах проект библиотеки появился, но я не могу получить к нему доступ из кода основного проекта используя import. Пытался подключить его в dependencies, но компилятор пишет ошибку Configuration with name 'default' not found. Читал по этой ошибке статьи, но ничего не понял. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, получилось. Прочитав ваше описание ошибки, не могу ничего посоветовать. Но совершенно точно вот этот библиотечный модуль должен быть в зависимостях (dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте библиотеку отдельным проектом и при компиляции публикуйте ее в каком-нибудь репозитории. В локальном Maven, к примеру.

А в любом проекте просто подключайте ее из репозитория, как и любую другую библиотеку.