# Подключение библиотек к Gradle проекту в Android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library

У меня есть проекты(библиотеки) лежат они к примеру в папке `C:\\Android\libs` и есть проекты к которым я хочу подключить эти библиотеки - они лежать по адресу `C:\\Android\projects` и я хочу что бы когда я вношу изменения в код библиотеки, заново ее собираю  после чего заново уже собираю сам проект приложения  то к нему подтягивались библиотеки с внесенными изменениями.

Но в структуре проекта я могу подключить библиотеки которые лежат в самом проекте по адресу `C:\Android\AndroidProjects\MyPoject\app\libs` а мне нужно их подтягивать с директории `C:\\Android\libs`, как такое можно организовать?

По предложенной ссылке делаю так:

1. есть `libraryone.aar` которая лежит по адресу `C:/Android/AndroidProjects/NetworkLib/library/build/outputs/aar`
2. в `settings.gradle`  пишу строки

   ```
   include ':libraryone'
   project(':libraryone').projectDir = new   File('C:/Android/AndroidProjects/NetworkLib/library/build/outputs/aar')
   ```
3. в ProjectStructure к модулю `app` добавляю в `dependencies` модуль `libraryone` после чего в build.gradle (module:app)  появляется следующая строчка     `compile project(':libraryone')`
4. Нажимаю на "собрать проект"  и ловлю  вот это: `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Comment: Если либа находится отдельном проекте(проект создан как библиотека), то она может находится где угодно. При Build-Rebuild перестроится все и в том числе проект с либой. Но я понимаю что это не то и тебе нужен знаток gradle.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Android Studio подключить в один проект другой, независимый от текущего](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483399/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-android-studio-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: @pavlofff, мне сложно оценить является ли этот вопрос копией предложенного вами, но я могу золотым дубль-хаммером закрыть... Закрывать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Подождите пожалуйста, проблема не решена, щас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: Так подключается проект из исходников, а не собранный в пакет.

Comment: @pavlofff т.е.  мне нужно указать путь не к файлу с библиотекой, а к самому проекту с исходниками библиотеки, т.е.нужно поменять путь на project(':libraryone').projectDir = new   File('C:/Android/AndroidProjects/NetworkLib/')  правильно?

Comment: @pavlofff Так хорошо, получилось но в таком случае не происходит merge Manifest.xml ,  можно ли как то таким образом сделать merge ?

Comment: Так все, разобрался. Закрывайте вопрос!