# Локальный репозиторий Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Столкнулся с весьма интересной проблемой. У меня есть два проекта. Первый проект - это моя Android библиотека (пока что не выложенная в сеть). Второй - это Android приложение, которое должно использовать первую библиотек.

Здача: после сборки Android библиотеки (читай, ее обновления), загружать ее во второй проект в автоматическом режиме. Номер версии библиотеки изменятся не будет.

---

Для решения этой задачи я вспомнил о очень интересной функции Maven - деплой в локальный репозиторий. То есть проект собирается, сразу же добавляется в локальный репозиторий и библиотека сразу появляется во всех проектах, где прописана зависимость (при условии, что номер версии не изменился).

Так же такой репозиторий позволяет работать с большим количеством изменяемых библиотек и никак не привязывается к конкретной структуре проекта.

---

Отсюда вопрос: а есть ли такая же функция деплоя в локальный репозиторий Gradle, а если и есть, то как пользоваться?

Comment: Для подключения одного проекта в другой смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483763/177345). Такое решение позволит вносить изменения в подключенный проект без необходимости что то менять в зависимостях и позволяет вести проекты независимо,но синхронизировать их. Так же не потребует подключения дополнительных модулей и плагинов, вроде maven

Comment: @pavlofff, действительно, Ваш вариант лучше в (рамках моей задачи). Преимущество Maven в том, что проект может лежать где угодно и не зависит от расположения папок, но, в таком случае, библиотеку лучше выложить в репозиторий и подключать через JCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
...
uploadArchives{
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://C://mvn")
            pom.version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            pom.artifactId = "deploy"
            pom.groupId = "com.example"
        }
    }
}
```