# Android Studio и библиотеки классов

Tags: android

Сделал я файл с классами, которые хочу использовать в разных проектах. В средах разработки 'старой' школы достаточно было бы добавить путь к файлу в library path. Относительно Android Studio я нашел только рекомендацию класть библиотечные файлы в подкаталог libs. Но для разных проектов это будет два разных каталога и два разных файла и если я буду менять один файл придется потом его вручную копировать в другое место (или в кучу других мест, если его будет использовать много проектов).

**Каково рекомендуемое решение для Android Studio?**

Comment: Тут палка о двух концах - если изменение библиотеки отразится на все проекты разом, то они могут поломаться. И потом открыв такой проект, чтобы скоренько пофиксить пару строк можно долго ломать голову отчего вдруг он перестал работать вообще.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483763/177345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо pavlofff за ссылку. Опубликую краткое резюме, чтобы было в одном месте. Основано на https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2014/10/03/an-alternative-multiproject-setup-for-android-studio/ (но в статье нет шагов 8-9, см. ниже).

Допустим, мы хотим, чтобы наша библиотека была в отдельном каталоге mylib.

1. Создаем новый пустой проект без активити. Как его назовем не важно, пусть будет mylibCont
2. В этом пустом проекте через File\New Module\Android Library создаем наш библиотечный каталог mylib. Имя библиотеки и модуля пишем mylib. Имя пакета задаем такое, какое нам надо, например ru.test.mylib.
3. Компилируем проект чтобы убедится, что все создалось как надо.
4. Теперь проект-оболочка нам не нужен. Копируем из него папку mylib в папку проектов, после чего папку проекта mylibCont удаляем (не люблю лишний мусор на диске).
5. Теперь в настоящем рабочем проекте в файле settings.gradle добавляем

```
include ':mylib'
project(':mylib').projectDir = new File("../mylib")
```

6. Делаем File\Sync Project with gradle files
7. В дереве проектов появится модуль mylib. Но этого мало!
8. Выбираем модуль app. Надо в файле build.gradle из модуля app добавить в секции dependencies

```
implementation project(':mylib')
```

9. Делаем File\Sync Project with gradle files
10. Все. Шаги 5-9 повторяем для каждого проекта, в котором хотим использовать нашу библиотеку.